# How to make JAX-WS use https (http to https) for soap:address in generated wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I am creating soap web service using jax-ws and spring. Here is my code

```
@WebService
@Service
public class SoapService {
    SoapServiceDao soapServiceDao;
    @WebMethod(exclude = true)
    public void setSoapServiceDao(SoapServiceDao soapServiceDao) {
        this.soapServiceDao = soapServiceDao;
    }

    @WebMethod
    @SOAPBinding(parameterStyle=ParameterStyle.BARE)
    public Message method1(SoapResponse soapResponse) {
        return new Message();
    }
}
```

and in application-context.xml

```
<wss:binding url="/soapservice">
    <wss:service>
        <ws:service bean="#soapserviceImpl" />
    </wss:service>
```

In generated wsdl

```
    <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/soapservice"/>
```

but i want **https** because my server accepts only https requests.

Is it possible to change http to https in this case?

Answer (score 0):

you may need to programmatically override the endpoint:
Try to change it as

```
MyServicePort myPort = new MyServiceInterface(new URL("https://acme.com/services/MyService.svc?wsdl")).getMyPort();
// set endpoint to use https
String endpointURL = "https://acme.com/services/MyService.svc";
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) myPort;
bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpointURL);``
myPort.test();
```

Comment: I am using Soap UI to test this,Where to write above code? In SoapService  class in method method1?

Comment: I think it would be better if u try this one https://coderanch.com/t/503621/java/Modify-WSDL-HTTP-HTTPS